# Ruby TCP server closes

Tags: ruby, tcp

I have a TCP server I start with the following command;

```
nohup ruby ./server.rb &
```

However, after a couple of days, this process is just closed and cannot trace the point when it breaks,

How do i keep the TCP server alive for ever until stopped.

Comment: You should add some logging and pipe STDERR to some file which can tell you why it broke.

Comment: you may want to add monitoring (God, Monit etc) to bring back the service in case it goes down (if that's your use case)

Comment: @kiddorails, i could use an example!

Comment: To pipe STDERR and STDOUT - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45915
Monit - http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit 
God - http://railscasts.com/episodes/130-monitoring-with-god

Comment: We can't really guess what's killing the server. You need to supply some (heavily) filtered log and/or stack-trace output, plus the bare minimum code that demonstrates the problem. Without that information we have to give answers which might help the symptom but won't fix the problem. Read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your process in a [daemon handler](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/daemonizing) so it gets restarted automatically.

You make a launcher script called something like `launcher.rb` that looks like this:

```
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run('myserver.rb')
```

Then, [as per the documentation](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons):

```
ruby launcher.rb start
```